# D3.js ~ Is there a way to access csv header values into a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm building an interactive graph that as the axis' values has two header values. It would be really better if I could chose the axis values from a drop down menu or something like that. What I don't know is if it's possible to access the header values of my csv like if they were part of an array, so I can make a dropdown menu to select from. Given a .csv that has many header values, and all of them are strings, is it possible to achieve this by using `d3.csv.formatRows(rows)`? I tried to use this inside the callback function with this:

```
var header = d3.csv("MyCsvFile.csv").formatRows(0);
console.log(header);
```

but didn't work. I'm not even sure I'm using the correct function, or if there is a function to do so! Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV) mentions the format that `d3.csv.parse` produces -- basically you will have key-value pairs with the header names as the keys. So all you need to do to get the header names is something like this.

```
d3.csv("foo.csv", function(error, data) {
  var headerNames = d3.keys(data[0]);
});
```

Comment: thanks! I was reading the documentation but as I'm not able to understand it completely I thought that parse would have worked, thanks for the fast response (will accept it when the timer expires!)

Comment: `d3.csv` uses `d3.csv.parse` internally, so there's no need to call it explicitly.

Comment: Question. This takes a long time. I have a very big CSV, millions of entries. Is there a way to only read the header without loading the whole file?

Comment: This reads in the entire CSV, which is way overkill if one only needs the headers.